# Can I have my pip user-installed package be preferred over system?

Tags: python, pip, setup.py, sys.path

I would like to figure out a "fool-proof" installation instruction to put in the README of a Python project, call it `footools`, such that other people in our group can install the newest SVN version of it on their laptops and their server accounts.

The problem is getting the user-installed libs to be used by Python when they call the scripts installed by pip. E.g., we're using a server that has an old version of footools in `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`.

If I do `python2.7 setup.py install --user` and run the main entry script, it uses the files in `/Users/unhammer/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/`. This is what I want, but setup.py alone doesn't install dependencies.

If I (revert the installation and) instead do `pip-2.7 install --user .` and run the main entry script, it uses the old files in `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` – that's not what I want.

If I (revert the installation and) instead do `pip-2.7 install --user -e .` and run the main entry script, it uses the files in `.` – that's not what I want, the user should be able to remove the source dir (and be able to svn up without that affecting their install).

---

I could use (and recommend other people to use) `python2.7 setup.py install --user` – but then they have to first do

```
pip-2.7 install -U --user -r requirements.txt -e .
pip-2.7 uninstall -y footools
```

in order to get the dependencies installed (since pip has no `install --only-deps` option). That's rather verbose though.

What is setup.py doing that pip is not doing here?

(Edited to make it clear I'm looking for simpler+safer installation instructions.)

Comment: Can you use virtualenv?

Comment: Could you please provide versions of setuptools and pip you were using? Also, how does entry script look like when you install with setuptools and when you install with pip? Can you run `python -m site` and `python -c "import os; print os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH')"` after each install and report results?

Comment: Piotr, there's a big discussion on it over at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/536 – for my own case, I no longer need a solution to this, but I'd recommend looking at that issue for anyone who does.

Comment: Are you saying your footools had the same version as the one installed already in system? In your question you state *If I (revert the installation and) instead do pip-2.7 install --user . and run the main entry script (...)*. How were you able to run *main entry script* if according to issue 536 your command `pip-2.7 install --user .` should be a no-op (if your version was the same as system one) so there shouldn't be any console script installed in bin directory of user install scheme?

Comment: If I recall correctly, the issue was that the version number of the already installed package was the same as the one in SVN, so pip didn't overwrite. By "revert the installation" I think I meant of the libs in ~/.local/site-python-whatever-it's-called, not the ~/bin loaders.

Answer (score 3):

Install `virtualenvwrapper`. I allows setting up separate python environments to alleviate any conflicts you might be having. [Here is a tutorial](http://simononsoftware.com/virtualenv-tutorial-part-2/) for installing and using virtualenv.

Related:

- https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: So … that's more work for the people installing, not less :-) I see the advantages of course, and may use it for my own workflow, but if the goal is to make installation more foolproof for other people then I'd have to write a whole virtualenvwrapper-wrapper which  doesn't quite seem worth it.

Comment: @unhammer: I understand your concern but it's currently the best solution. Installing `virtualenvwrapper` is very easy unless you're on Windows where the best option is probably to switch to Python 3 which comes with such a tool. The main problem with PIP is that it changes the default Python installation which potentially breaks other code. Your fix - installing in a user supplied place - helps but the venv tools for Python solve other problems as well which you didn't run into, yet.

Answer (score 1):

Console scripts generated by pip in the process of installation should use user installed versions of libraries as according to PEP 370:

> The user site directory is added before the system site directories
>   but after Python's search paths and PYTHONPATH. **This setup allows the
>   user to install a different version of a package than the system
>   administrator** but it prevents the user from accidently overwriting a
>   stdlib module. Stdlib modules can still be overwritten with
>   PYTHONPATH.

Sidenote

---

Setuptools use hack by inserting code in `easy_install.pth` file which is placed in `site-packages` directory. This code makes packages installed with setuptools come before other packages in `sys.path` so they *shadow* other packages with the same name. This is referred to as *sys.path modification* in the [table](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/pip_easy_install/?highlight=path%20modification) comparing setuptools and pip. This is the reason console scripts use user installed libraries when you install with `setup.py install` instead of using pip.

---

Taking all of the above into account the reason for what you observe might be caused by:

- PYTHONPATH pointing to directories with system-wide installed libraries
- Having system-wide libraries installed using `sudo python.py install (...)`
- Having OS influence `sys.path` construction in some way

In the first case either clearing PYTHONPATH or adding path to user installed library to the beginning of PYTHONPATH should help.
In the second case uninstalling system-wide libraries and installing them with distro package manager instead might help (please note that you never should use sudo with pip or setup.py to install Python packages).
In the third case it's necessary to find out how does OS influence `sys.path` construction and if there's some way of placing user installed libraries before system ones.

You might be interested in reading issue [pip list reports wrong version of package installed both in system site and user site](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1018) where I asked basically the same question as you:

> Does it mean that having system wide Python packages installed with easy_install thus having them use sys.path manipulation breaks scripts from user bin directory? If so is there any workaround?

Last resort *solution* would be to manually place directory/directories with user installed libraries in the beginning of `sys.path` from your scripts before importing these libraries.

Having said that if your users do not need direct access to source code I would propose packaging your app together with all dependencies using tool like [pex](https://pex.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or [Platter](http://platter.pocoo.org/dev/) into self-contained *bundle*.